# I created an inherited class called "Cartel" from the class "Surface", but the image I want to "blit" appears in black (and others do not)

Tags: python, class, pygame

I created a class `Cartel`, which inherits from `pygame.surface.Surface`, to display images

```py
class Cartel(pygame.surface.Surface):
    def __init__(self,width, height,imagen):
        super().__init__((width, height))
        self.imagen=pygame.image.load(imagen).convert_alpha()
        pantalla.blit(self,(200,180))
```

Although when I try using the `Cartel` class the image appears in black

```py
while True:
    fon2=Cartel(300,300,"Images\circulo.png")
```

But this doesn't happen when I `blit` an image normally, like this:

```py
francia=pygame.image.load("Images\Francia.png").convert_alpha()
francia=pygame.transform.scale(francia, (150, 40))
francia_rect=francia.get_rect(center=(70,60))

while True:
    pantalla.blit(francia,francia_rect)
```

I'd like to know how to blit correclty an image from my class. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way your approach looks I don't think your class needs to inherit `pygame.surface.Surface`. It would be easyer to just store the screen and image object in your class. Then you could have a blit method that draws the image to the screen. You just would have to call that method in your game look for the image to display. This would also get rid of the need to reinstantiate the class every tick.

Here is an example of the class

```py
class Cartel:
    def __init__(self, image, screen):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.screen = screen

    def blit(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (200, 280))
```

And your game loop could look something like this

```py
cartel = Cartel("image.jpg", screen)
while True:
    cartel.blit()
    pygame.display.flip()
```